# Cannot install steam Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, steam

I cannot install a steam on ubuntu 14.10. I haven`t had this problem before.

```
Selecting previously unselected package steam-launcher.
(Reading database ... 218661 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack steam.deb ...
Unpacking steam-launcher (1.0.0.49) ...
Setting up steam-launcher (1.0.0.49) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.10.20140925-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
kvach@kvach-pc:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150209211914_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/kvach/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730: 13925 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/kvach/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/kvach/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/kvach/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150209211916_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/kvach/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730: 14051 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: I have tried. Didn`t help.

Comment: What was the output? Same? Or no action taken?

Comment: Just checking, but have you rebooted? You probably have, but it never hurts to check :)

Comment: Actually I have installed steam-launcher, but then I cannot install fully. When I type "steam" in terminal I got this error above. sudo apt-get install -f change nothing. @RPi Awesomeness I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx guys for ur tryings. I have installed it through synaptic along with one more package which has been suggested by synaptic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing libcurl.so. Have you moved/modified it?

try reinstalling whichever version of libcurl you have:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Comment: I don`t know. What is this?

Comment: do you have curl installed?  try from terminal 'which curl'

Comment: @sam: Can you please explain how to install `libcurl.so`?

Comment: Im not on an Ubuntu machine at this moment but it should be something close to `sudo apt-get install curl`